# How to combine multiple bool queries in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to create the equivalent of the following query -

```
(city = 'New York' AND state = 'NY') AND ((businessName='Java' and businessName='Shop') OR (category='Java' and category = 'Shop'))
```

I tried different combinations of bool queries using must and should but nothing seems to be working. Can this be done?

Comment: what is not working - can you elaborate?

Comment: I am not able to come up with the right syntax. Always get some parsing exception.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "filter": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "city": "New york"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "state": "NY"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "bool": {
                                    "must": [
                                        {
                                            "term": {
                                                "businessName": "Java"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "term": {
                                                "businessName": "Shop"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "bool": {
                                    "must": [
                                        {
                                            "term": {
                                                "category": "Java"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "term": {
                                                "category": "Shop"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you might add `minimum_should_match` for `should` query

Comment: Still working in v7.5 - don't forget to remove/check the placement of ```minimum_should_match``` for queries as you could end up getting no results at all if you'r having a ```must``` query.