# passing multiple combination query in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

```
`"query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [],
                    "should": [],
                    "filter": [
                        {
                            "terms": {
                                "category": "type-1",
                                "product": "product-A"
                            },
                            "terms": {
                                "category": "type-2",
                                "product": "product-B"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "functions": []
        }
    },`
```

I want to pass multiple combination query like above is it possible, what should be the correct query format

in sql my query would be

select * from product where (category='type1' and product=product-A) or (category='type2' and product=product-B) or (category='type3' and product=product-C)

i want to replicate above query

Comment: How would you expect this result ? Are you filtering your results of a filter ? .. It's not clear..

Comment: Also this **may** be related.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36389513/how-to-combine-multiple-bool-queries-in-elasticsearch?rq=1

Comment: i want a query equivalent  to (category=type-1 and product=product-A) or (category=type-2 and product=product-B) because there may be product-A in type-2 category or product-B in type-1 category i want product of particular category

Comment: @Pogrindis i am not sure about my query i am still trying if must,should or filter any thing working for me or not

Comment: @NikhilBhivgade, can you update the mapping along with query?

Comment: yes i can update the mapping

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a `OR` statement in a bool query you should is a nested `bool` query with multiple `should` clause.

so try :

```
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [],
                    "should": [],
                    "filter": [
                        {
                            "bool": {
                                "should": [
                                    {
                                        "bool": {
                                            "must": [
                                                {
                                                    "term": {
                                                        "category": "type-1"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "term": {
                                                        "product": "product-A"
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "bool": {
                                            "must": [
                                                {
                                                    "term": {
                                                        "category": "type-2"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "term": {
                                                        "product": "product-B"
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "functions": []
}
```

and if you have no `must` clause you can move your filters clauses into the main `should` as only document that matchs at least one of the clause will match.

Comment: getting error : "reason":"[term] query doesn't support multiple fields

Comment: oups sorry, i rewrite the queries to use nested bool to handle the AND logic