# Aggreagate results based on 3 different elasticsearch queries

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 3 different search queries coming from different sources, I want to aggregate these queries in to a single query that will return the results that is union of these 3 queries (OR operation on query)

For example:

Query 1:

```
query: {
  bool: {
    filter: [
      { terms: { tags.keyword: ['apple', 'banana'] }},
      { terms: { language.keyword: ['en'] }},
    ]
  }
}
```

Query 2:

```
query: {
  bool: {
    filter: [
      { terms: { tags.keyword: ['orange', 'mango'] }},
      { terms: { language.keyword: ['it'] }}, 
      { terms: { source.keyword: ['Royal Garden'] }},
    ]
  }
}
```

Query 3:

```
query: {
  bool: {
    filter: [
      { terms: { owner.keyword: ['Dan Chunmun'] }},
      { terms: { language.keyword: ['en'] }}, 
      { terms: { source.keyword: ['Royal Garden'] }},
    ]
  }
}
```

I what to have the search result that is:

> Result = Query 1 OR Query 2 OR Query 3 (Union of all 3 queries)

I was looking at [How to combine multiple bool queries in elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36389513/how-to-combine-multiple-bool-queries-in-elasticsearch/36390660) question, but there it is not explained how to merge the query.
I tried using `should` clause but not able to get the expected result so far.

I tried combining the `bool` part of the queries above like:

```
const boolTerms: any = [];

Queries.map(q => {
  return boolTerms.push(q.query);
});

// combined query
filter : {
  bool: {
    should: boolTerms  
  }
}
```

Comment: please do add which language are u using to combine queries and secondly include the query represented by "boolTerms"

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways for combining queries

1. Query string query is meant for these use cases only. In query string query you can write each and every query in a string format

Let define a clause A=**tags.keyword: ['apple', 'banana']**

Now way you can combine multiple is this

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "(A and B) OR (D and E and F) or(G and H and E)"
    }
  }
}
```

Here A and B are all clauses of query 1.

2. But since query string query is a full-text query and analyzers will be applied to query terms, so for your case bool query would be used, in which you can combine tern queries as well

**Here is an Example**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
     "should": [
       {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "tags.keyword":  ["apple", "banana"]
              }
            },
            {
              "terms": {
                "language.keyword":  ["en"]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
       },
       {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "tags.keyword":  ["orange", "banana"]
              }
            },
            {
              "terms": {
                "language.keyword":  ["it"]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
       }
     ]
    }
  }
}
```