# elasticsearch: can remove duplicate field in query?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I would like to remove duplicated field in query.
For example:

```
# figure1 

{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": []
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

in above query example base,
Is it possible to remove duplicate `bool` fields except for the first `bool`?

The result I want is below

```
# figure2

{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "should": [
            {
              "must": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

please, I hope wating for your answer, thanks.

Comment: Please elaborate on what do you want to achieve.

Comment: @Netanel Malka I wonder if it will remove duplicate query fields. (Can the figure1 case query above be improved like the figure2 example query?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.
With figure #2 elastic throws an error:

```
[should] query malformed, no start_object after query name
```

If you want to create a nested boolean expression, you must put the keyword `bool` before.

For example:
[How to combine multiple bool queries in elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36389513/how-to-combine-multiple-bool-queries-in-elasticsearch)